# Lightning create sticky button

Tags: lightning, slds

When I was discovering my Salesforce, I found that if you trigger an inline edit on standard record view, the whole component becomes editable and button "Save" and "Cancel" are sticky to the bottom of container.

Is there a way to implement the same in custom lightning component by standard 
SLDS tools?

[image: sticky button example]

Answer (score 5):

In case you still need it ;)

```
<div class="slds-utility-bar slds-align_absolute-center "  > 
  <lightning:button variant="brand" label="Submit" onclick="{! c.submit }" />
</div>
```

[image]